# GluonVM launching on iOS Device [issues]

Tags: ios, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am giving a try of GluonVM on iOS with Oracle JDK 10.2.
I have noticed that although I have "com.javasuns.test" in **src/ios/Default-Info.plist**, when I run the **"./gradlew launchIOSDevice"** command, the bundle ID is taken from the **mainClassName** defined in **build.gradle**.

Here is my example:

**Default-Info.plist**

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.javasuns.test</string>
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

mainClassName = 'test.TestFX'

fxmobile {
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.12'
    ios { ...... }
}
```

**./gradlew launchIOSDevice**

```
com.gluonhq.higgs.Higgs: non-fatal issue for class javafx.scene.web.JSObjectIosImpl (no known superclass) 
command to dsymutil: xcrun dsymutil -o /Volumes/MyApps/testFX/build/gvm/testFX.app.dSYM /Volumes/MyApps/testFX/build/gvm/testFX.app/testFX 
Error getting ProvisioninedDevices, ignore
created
created
created
created
Error getting ProvisioninedDevices, ignore
created
provprofile asked, bid = test.TestFX and origbid = test.TestFX
provprofile asked, bid = test.* and origbid = test.TestFX
provprofile asked, bid = * and origbid = test.TestFX
No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: #NAME#' and app bundle ID 'test.TestFX'
will return PP null
No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: #NAME#' and app bundle ID 'test.TestFX'
will return PP null
No provisioning profile found matching signing identity 'iPhone Developer: #NAME#' and app bundle ID 'test.TestFX'
will return PP null
Warning, getProvisioningProfile is failing
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have managed to bypass the issue by creating a new java main class named "**test.java**" under **"com.javasuns"** package (ignoring that java type names usually start with an uppercase letter).

**build.gradle (Changed)**

```
mainClassName = 'com.javasuns.test'
```

However, now a new error appears that I do not know how to get through it:

```
13:17:45:491] BosonAppSupport: Validating codesign... 
[SUB] /Volumes/MyApps/testFX/build/gvm/testFX.app: valid on disk
[SUB] /Volumes/MyApps/testFX/build/gvm/testFX.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
[13:17:46:269] BosonAppSupport: Validation codesign result: true 
[13:17:46:270] BosonAppSupport: Codesign done 
[13:17:46:333] BosonAppBuilder: UploadInternal start 
[13:17:51:041] : Upload Progress: 10% 
[13:17:51:573] : Upload Progress: 20% 
[13:17:52:104] : Upload Progress: 30% 
[13:17:52:916] : Upload Progress: 40% 
[13:17:53:947] : Upload Progress: 50% 
[13:17:54:696] : Upload Progress: 60% 
[13:17:55:520] : Upload Progress: 70% 
[13:17:56:372] : Upload Progress: 80% 
[13:17:57:367] : Upload Progress: 90% 
[13:17:58:414] : Upload Progress: 100% 
[13:17:58:460] BosonAppBuilder: uploadInternal done 

[13:17:58:796] : Progress: CreatingStagingDirectory [5%] 
[13:17:58:798] : Progress: ExtractingPackage [15%] 
[13:17:58:799] : Progress: InspectingPackage [20%] 
[13:17:58:802] : Progress: TakingInstallLock [20%] 
[13:17:58:804] : Progress: PreflightingApplication [30%] 
[13:17:58:805] : Progress: InstallingEmbeddedProfile [30%] 
[13:17:58:812] : Progress: VerifyingApplication [40%] 
[13:17:58:954] : Error: APIInternalError, Description: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LXITKr/extracted/testFX.app/TestApp

> Task :launchIOSDevice
[13:17:58:955] BosonAppBuilder: Installing finished due to an error. 
[13:17:58:958] BosonAppBuilder: Install internal failed 
[13:17:58:958] BosonAppBuilder: Something went wrong. App wasn't installed on the device
```

Any ideas of how I can solve both issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main keys that you have to set properly: `CFBundleIdentifier` and `CFBundleExecutable`.

You can check the sample [SingleView-GluonVM](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/singleview-gluonvm):

- Main className (see [build.gradle](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/singleview-gluonvm/singleview-gluonvmApp/build.gradle#L23)): `com.gluonhq.samples.singleviewgvm.SingleViewWithGluonVM`
- CFBundleIdentifier (see [Default-info.plist](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/singleview-gluonvm/singleview-gluonvmApp/src/ios/Default-Info.plist#L6)): `com.gluonhq.samples.singleviewgvm.SingleViewWithGluonVM`

and

- Gradle project (see [settings.gradle](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/singleview-gluonvm/settings.gradle)): `singleview-gluonvmApp`
- CFBundleExecutable (see [Default-info.plist](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/blob/master/singleview-gluonvm/singleview-gluonvmApp/src/ios/Default-Info.plist#L12)): `singleview-gluonvmApp`

or the sample [DeepLearning-LinearClassifier](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/deeplearning-linearclassifier), with similar settings.

As you can see, the Gluon IDE plugin sets by default the `CFBundleIdentifier` as the main class name and the `CFBundleExecutable` as the name of your mobile project.

**CFBundleIdentifier**

When you want to deploy your app to iOS, the provisioning profile should have this bundle ID. However, you can also use wildcards. Just make sure you have downloaded and installed to your machine the provisioning profile (it should be under `/Users/<user>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`), with extension `.mobileprovision`.

If you preview it (from Finder for instance), the AppID from this file could be something like `<TEAM ID>.<mainClassName>`, or `<TEAM ID>.*`.

[This](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/Gvm.java#L77) is where the jfxmobile plugin sets the `appId`.

**CFBundleExecutable**

About the `CFBundleExecutable`, this is the name your application under `build/gvm/` will have. It is mandatory in this case that it uses the name of your project (as in the gradle name).

[This](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/Gvm.java#L78) is where the jfxmobile plugin sets the `appName`.

You will find your app under `/<appName>/build/gvm/<appName>.app` (though Finder will show just `<appName>`:

[image]

If you see the content of the app, you will find the executable file under `/<appName>/build/gvm/<appName>.app/<appName>`:

[image]

The error you are getting;

> [13:17:58:954] : Error: APIInternalError, Description: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.LXITKr/extracted/testFX.app/TestApp

shows `testFX.app/TestApp`, so probably your project name is `testFX`, but should be `TestApp`?

Alternatively, you can simple match the value you have set in `CFBundleExecutable`, by adding a `settings.gradle` file to your project, with:

```
rootProject.name = "<your bundle executable value>"
```

Comment: Maybe i did not understand something here, but what if i do not want my "CFBundleIdentifier" to be the same as "Main className". Let's say for example that for some reason I need to change the main java class name. then it would be mandatory to go and create a new bundle id, right? Is this necessary? Also, from what i've noticed so far, Apple's bundle ids are all in non-capital words and not in the form that it has to be followed through GluonVM, i.e. <package>.<JavaMain>.

Comment: You are right. This is a limitation in the current plugin. The new Gluon Client plugin solves that issue. While it is still in development, you can already try the samples [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples). In the meantime, did you manage to deploy your app to iOS?

Comment: Well i just tried now with the change you mentioned in gradle.properties and it solved the issue with the “APIInternalError”. However, it seems that it fails to run the preloader class, although there is no problem with RoboVM version

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. You could file it [here](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues), but note that all the efforts are now in the Client plugin.

Comment: Is GluonVM going to be dropped and taken over by GraalVM? Does Client support preloaders?

Comment: Actually, is the Client result of a combination of GluonVM and GraalVM, among other things. Preloader support will be added, not there yet.

Comment: Well looking forward to it. I mean it would be great seeing it reaching the feature level of old RoboVM/MobiVM. I admire your work. Although, I had said it before, I’ll say it again. Thank you for everything

Comment: Thanks for your words and support. Adding more features to the plugin will be the easier part.